# Is it possible to use @Parameter in a REST controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, openapi-generator

I'm trying to use `@Parameter` for a path parameter in a `@RestController`, but it ignores the parameter.

**Note**: All works well if I use `@PathVariable` instead (commented). However, `@PathVariable` does not produce the OpenAPI yaml file with all properties like "description", "references", etc, that the `springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin` produces automatically.

Is it possible to use `@Parameter` in a REST controller?

Here's my code:

```
@RequestMapping("/channels")
@RestController
public class ChannelRESTController {

  @PostMapping("{channelId}/connect")
  @Operation(summary = "Initiates a session to a channel", tags = { "session" })
  @ResponseBody
  ResponseEntity<?> connect( //
      @Parameter(name = "channelId", in = ParameterIn.PATH, 
                 required = true, description = "The channel id") String channelId,
      // @PathVariable(required = true) String channelId,
      @Parameter(description = "Credentials' username") String username,
      @Parameter(description = "Credentials' password") String password
  ) {
    System.out.println(
        "Starting channel #" + channelId); // displays null :(
    return ...
  }
```

Comment: You _can_ use both.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Oh... didn't think about that. It works!

Comment: If your question is answered please add the ansewr

Answer (score 1):

In order to automate the OpenAPI YAML file generation it's possible to add both annotations to the parameters.

In short, the parameter `channelId` above can be annotated as:

```
  @PathVariable(required = true) 
  @Parameter(name = "channelId", in = ParameterIn.PATH, 
             required = true, description = "The channel id")
  String channelId,
```

In this case:

- the first annotation `@PathVariable` allows Spring to retrieve the parameter from the URL.
- the second annnotation `@Parameter` produces the correct description in OpenAPI (YAML) file generated by the `springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin` plugin.

This solution is not ideal, but does the trick. I wish in the future the plugin will recognize the second one by itself, to avoid typing them both.